# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate for updating more than one fields in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am using mongoose version 5.9.25 and I am using postman for API testing.

I trying to build RESTful API but while using route.put() along with `findOneAndUpdate` method and finding document by using title field.

My document contains two fields - title and content and I want to update both. It only updates the title of my document whereas content field is not even added to object.

I have tried using native MongoBD driver `findOneAndUpdate` method directly through mongo console and it works prefectly fine.

I want to update the object with new title and content using mongoose and the following code is not giving the desired outputs [Before put request-- Notice the object id is same in both images but only the title field is updated after PUT request as shown in image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY2p7.jpg).

This is my update route:

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
  .put(function(req,res){
    Article.findOneAndUpdate(
      {title:req.params.articleTitle},
      {title: req.body.title ,content: req.body.content},
      {overwrite: true},
      function(err,result){
      if(!err){

        res.send(result);
      }
      else{
        res.send(err);

      }
    });
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have a syntax error. You need to use the [set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, change the update portion of the code from:

```
{title: req.body.title ,content: req.body.content}
```

To this:

```
{$set: {title: req.body.title ,content: req.body.content}},
```

Also you should use the `new` option instead of `overwrite` which I think is only available for the `update` operator but not for the `findOneAnd..` operators.

Full:

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
    .put(function(req,res){
        Article.findOneAndUpdate(
            {title:req.params.articleTitle},
            {$set: {title: req.body.title ,content: req.body.content}},
            {new: true},
            function(err,result){
                if(!err){

                    res.send(result);
                }
                else{
                    res.send(err);

                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: You can use `findOneAndReplace` instead if you want to have that `overwrite` behaviour.